# How &a[i][j] gets evaluated to *(a+i)+j

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

if I want address of a[2][3] using *(a+i)+j

According to me,*(a+2) will give me 3(considering row order) and j = 3 so it is evaluated as 3+3=6

How it will give address?

Comment: are you sure you want the address of a[2][3]? It's out of bounds because in C indices start at 0, not at 1

Comment: i want for a[1][2]

Answer (score 1):

As you apparently know, `&a[2][3]` is defined to be `*(a+2)+3`. Here is how that expression is evaluated:

1. `a` is an array of 3 arrays of 3 `int`. The elements of `a` are `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`.
2. When `a` is used used in the expression `a+2`, `a` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `a` becomes `&a[0]`, a pointer to `a[0]`.
3. By definition of `+` for pointers, adding `2` to a pointer to `a[0]` produces a pointer to `a[2]`. So `a+2` is `&a[2]`.
4. Then `*(a+2)` is the object pointed to by `a+2`, so it is `a[2]`.
5. So `*(a+2)+3` is `a[2]+3`.
6. `a[2]` is an array of 3 `int`. It elements are `a[2][0]`, `a[2][1]`, and `a[2][2]`.
7. In the expression `a[2]+3`, `a[2]` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `a[2]` becomes `&a[2][0]`, and the expression is `&a[2][0] + 3`.
8. By definition of `+` for pointers, adding `3` to a pointer to `a[2][0]` would produce a pointer to `a[2][3]`. There is no element `a[2][3]`, but pointer arithmetic is allowed to go just beyond the end of an array—you can use that pointer as an endpoint, although there is no defined element there, and you should not dereference the pointer.

So `*(a+2)+3` gives the address just beyond the end of the subarray `a[2]`.

Comment: so in a 2d array a[2] will act like a array pointer to the first element of the a[2] row i.e array

Comment: in 5th statement Acording to you *(a+2)+3 is a[2]+3,  then how *(a+2)+3 will give the address?

Comment: @Pranjalakg: In step 5, `*(a+2)+3` is shown to be `a[2]+3`. In step 7, `a[2]` is converted to `&a[2][0]`, so we have `&a[2][0]+3`, which is an address plus an integer. In step 8, that addition produces the address of `a[2][3]`.

Comment: thanks a lot but according to step 8 (a+2)+3 should give the address not *(a+2)+3 i.e the only one final doubt i have ?

Comment: @Pranjalakg: In `*(a+2)+3`, `*(a+2)` is the array `a[2]`, and it is automatically converted to `&a[2][0]`, and then adding 3 gives `&a[2][3]`. In `(a+2)+3`, `a` is `&a[0]`, so `a+2` is `&a[2]`, and then `(a+2)+3` would be `&a[2]+3`, which would be `&a[5]`, which is invalid because it is too far beyond the end of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete **j(3)** and add **3** to **i**. There is no need to add **j**. *a is adress of first element of the array. **a=1, so *a + 2 means you add **2** to adress of first element and it becomes address of the third element. **(*a +5)** is the adress of the **a[2][3]**.Also your assignment should be **a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};**

Answer (score 0):

Simple - if

```
a[i] == *(a + i)
```

then

```
a[i][j] == *(a[i] + j) == *(*(a + i) + j)
```

therefore

```
&a[i][j] == *(a + i) + j
```

The *expression* `a[i]` has type "3-element array of `int`".  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, it will be converted, or "decay" to type "pointer to `int`", or `int *`. So `a[i] + j` gives you a pointer value, not an integer value.